# Class Objects Inappropriately Sharing Attribute

Tags: python, class, attributes

I have a class with an attribute. Originally it held a single string of an error message. I thought I would get clever and turn it into a list so every time I 'set' the attribute, rather than replacing the string it would append the string to a list.

Now, however, the `err` attribute is shared amongst the objects rather than being unique for each one.

Here is my code (`test.py`, trimmed to just the minimum for this example)

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3
# pylint: disable=C0301

'''Testing MyHost class'''

class MyHostGood:           # pylint: disable=R0903
    '''Host class'''
    err = ''
    name = ''

    def __init__(self, name=''):
        '''Constructor'''
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        '''Return a printable user representation of the object - print(x)'''
        info = f'{self.name}:'
        # These are error/warning messages
        if self.err:
            info += f'\n└ ERROR: {self.err}'
        return info

class MyHostBad:           # pylint: disable=R0903
    '''Host class'''
    _err = []
    name = ''

    def __init__(self, name=''):
        '''Constructor'''
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        '''Return a printable user representation of the object - print(x)'''
        info = f'{self.name}:'
        # These are error/warning messages
        if self._err:
            for errMsg in self._err:
                info += f'\n└ ERROR: {errMsg}'
        return info

    @property
    def err(self):
        '''Return the list of error messages'''
        return self._err

    @err.setter
    def err(self, arg):
        '''Add another string to the error messages'''
        if isinstance(arg, str):
            self._err.append(arg)
        if isinstance(arg, list):
            self._err.extend(arg)
```

Here is the good class where the `err` attribute is unique:

```
>>> import test
>>> a = test.MyHostGood('foo')
>>> a.err = 'Here is one error string'
>>> print(a)
foo:
└ ERROR: Here is one error string
>>> b = test.MyHostGood('bar')
>>> print(b)
bar:
>>> b.err = 'a new error'
>>> print(a)
foo:
└ ERROR: Here is one error string
>>> print(b)
bar:
└ ERROR: a new error
>>>
```

And here the `err` attribute is now shared between the objects:

```
>>> import test
>>> c = test.MyHostBad('wiz')
>>> c.err = 'Here is one error string'
>>> print(c)
wiz:
└ ERROR: Here is one error string
>>> d = test.MyHostBad('baz')
>>> print(d)
baz:
└ ERROR: Here is one error string
>>> d.err = 'a new error'
>>> print(c)
wiz:
└ ERROR: Here is one error string
└ ERROR: a new error
>>> print(d)
baz:
└ ERROR: Here is one error string
└ ERROR: a new error
>>>
```

How do I fix the getter/setter so the objects have their own error strings again?

Comment: It isn't inappropriately sharing anything. **You created a class variable**, which is shared by all instances of the class. If y ou don't want a class variable, use an instance variable. "Now, however, the err attribute is shared amongst the objects rather than being unique for each one." *of course*. You really should read the [official tutorial on class definitions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) this should really be a first step before asking a question on stack overflow

Comment: Thank you for the reference @juanpa-arrivillaga. I'll look into it.

Comment: If I've been creating class variables, I'm not sure why `err` wasn't shared in the `MyHostGood` example. Nonetheless, it looks like I need to adjust my coding.

Comment: It *was* shared, but doing `self.error += whatever` **shadowed** the class variable with an instance variable, and created a new object since `str` objects are immutable. If you did this with a list, `self.error += [1,2,]` it woudl do the same thing, but now the instance variable and class variable are referring to the same object. If you did `self.error = self.error + [1,2,3]`, it would *shadow* the class variable with an instance variable, but it would be two different lists.

Comment: You basically should stop using class variables like this, they serve no purpose, you should be using instance variables.

Comment: Agreed. Thank you for your insight (and your documentation recommendation). I'm learning how classes work and need to correct my coding. Pylint doesn't catch everything! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_err` is a class variable, shared by all objects. Since the setter method modifies it in place, changes are visible to all objects. To fix this, make `_err` into an object attribute by modifying the constructor of `MyHostBad`:

```
def __init__(self, name=''):
    '''Constructor'''
    self.name = name
    self._err = []
```

Comment: Thank you @bb1! While that works, I don't quite understand what is going on. In this example, the variables outside of the constructor aren't shared:
```
>>> class myClass:
...     a = '1'
...     def __init__(self):
...         print(self.a)
...
>>> x = myClass()
1
>>> y = myClass()
1
>>>
>>> x.a = 'xyzzy'
>>> print(x.a)
xyzzy
>>> print(y.a)
1
>>>
```

Comment: @shepster because `x.a = 'xyxxy'` **creates an instance variable on that instance**. The class variable is still there

Comment: @shepster The difference is that lists are mutable. When you append to a list, you modify the list in place without making a copy. For this reason, all instances of MyHostBad were using the same list. On the other hand, strings are not mutable, so when an instance of myClass modifies the variable `a`, it creates a new value that is visible to that instance only, while the class variable stays unchanged.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all your explanation. I had poor programming practices that were hidden due to the immutability of strings. I know better how to code my class objects!